# Repeating a process can be a situation for method overloading?

Tags: java

I am developing a converter from objects of different domains, which accepts both, converting one object to other, or a list to another list.
Please consider the following example:

```
public MyObject2 decode(MyObject1 originalObject) {
    String name = String.valueOf(originalObject.getId());

    return MyObject2(name);
}

public List<MyObject2> decodeList(Collection<MyObject1> originalObjectsList) {
    return originalObjectsList.stream().map(this::decode).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

My situation much more complex than this, but for the sake of argument this is enough.

At my team, we came with the doubt of what should be better in terms of Software Design and future understanding of the code. Prefer the method `decodeList()` with this exactly signature, or change it to overload `decode()`.

For me is difficult to say, because both look right. Overloading looks cleaner, but `decodeList()` also makes sense to me if you consider that repeating the same process multiple times deserves to be treated as different thing.

Is there any best practices related to this kind of situation?

Comment: Semantically, both methods are different.  It makes sense to give the two methods different names to make this clear to consuming developers.  This recent question covers the same topic: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/313263/benefit-of-not-overloading-abstractcollection-add-and-having-abstractcollec

Comment: I agree with @MetaFight.  You are likely to use `decodeList` with other list operations (loops, iterators, etc..) whereas the `decode` will be used individually or within the body of those loops.  As @MetaFight points out, in the general case, one may want a separate meaning for `decode ( list_item )` vs. `decodeList ( list_item )`, e.g. decode a reference to a list vs. decode a collection of items.

Comment: @MetaFight I see, but I have to say, I would never find that question :P
I tried to do it in a more generic way thinking that it my be util for future reading.

Comment: @PatrickBard, I wasn't trying to say your question was a duplicate.  I was just pointing out that the crux of this question had recently been discussed in the other question.

Comment: @MetaFight Yeah, I got it. I was just commenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

caveat/excuse for potentially stupid answer: I C#.

*To overload or not to overload that is...*  not the question. Overloading is fine here but for "future understanding of the code" I suggest the question is class design. I'd want to see the functionality in one place.

I don't know where the above methods are but I wonder if they could both be in the same class. Perhaps a generic collection class.

```
public class ObjectCollectionConverter<T, V> {
    public T decodeObject (V originalObject) {}
    public V decodeObject (T originalObject) {}

    public List<V> decodeList(Collection<T> (originalObjectList)
    public List<T> decodeList(Collection<V> (originalObjectList)
}

// The above could be static I suppose, in which case
// the class name might be `ObjectConverter`
```

1. Remove the `decode` from the `Objectn` class. This is good in terms of Single Responsibility Principle.
2. The above seems good if there is a strong relationship / correlation in business domain terms between these two, or any two, `Objectn` classes.
3. Depending on your requirements/domain the class and/or methods could be `static`.
4. This converter class suggests an `interface` may be in order to guarantee the presence of `decode` method. But if we're talking only about `Object1` and `Object2` classes then it is not necessary.
5. You might define a `delegate` for the decode method which could allow more flexibility, And an `interface` would not be necessary in this case.
6. Class composition flexibility.